# Preserve big.mark = " " when updating modify_header() of gt_summary object

Tags: r, gtsummary

Setting big.mark with

```
theme_gtsummary_language("en", big.mark = " ")
```

is handy and works. See [gtsummary R package: how to remove commas when printing large numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63801918/gtsummary-r-package-how-to-remove-commas-when-printing-large-numbers)

However, I struggle to find a way to preserve this formatting in the header when using `modify_header()`

```
theme_gtsummary_language("en", big.mark = " ")

ggplot2::diamonds %>%
  select(cut) %>%
  tbl_summary()%>%
  modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**, \n N = {n}")
```

[image]

See the header does not have the big.mark = " " formatting.

Any hacks, workarounds or "official" code is appreciated.

- In my own work i usually print these as a flextable so if there are any updates I can do there that can also work.

Comment: This is a great question (and a confusing point!). The reason it's not being preserved when you add `{n}` to the header is because `{n}` is a numeric scalar (not a pre-formatted string). If you would like the gtsummary theme to be respected, you can use the `style_number()` function, e.g. `modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**, \n N = {style_number(n)}")`

Answer (score 1):

Possible workaround with `scales::number()`:

```r
library(gtsummary)

theme_gtsummary_language("en", big.mark = " ")

ggplot2::diamonds %>%
  select(cut) %>%
  tbl_summary() %>%
  modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**, N = {scales::number(n)}")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-19 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>